# Any way to avoid results containing "9.223372036854776E18"

Tags: java, math, number-formatting

I'm making a program that turns a large number into a string, and then adds the characters of that string up. It works fine, my only problem is that instead of having it as a normal number, Java converts my number into standard form, which makes it hard to parse the string. Are there any solutions to this?

```
public static void main(String ags[]) {
    long nq = (long) Math.pow(2l, 1000l);
    long result = 0;
    String tempQuestion = Double.toString(nq);
    System.out.println(tempQuestion);
    String question = tempQuestion.substring(0, tempQuestion.length() - 2);
    for (int count = 0; count < question.length(); count++) {
        String stringResult = question.substring(count, count + 1);
        result += Double.parseDouble(stringResult);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: What would be a 'normal' number in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers are correct, you could use a `java.text.NumberFormat` ([JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)) to format your output. Using `printf`is also an option for formatting, similar to `NumberFormat`. But I see something else here. It looks like you mixed up your data types: In

`nq = (long) Math.pow(2l, 1000l);`

you are already truncating the double return value from Math to a long. Then you should use `long` as data type instead of `double` for the conversion. So use  `Long.toString(long)`, this will not add any exponent output.

Use `Long.toString(nq)` instead of `Double.toString(nq)`; in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As you say: "NumberFormat". The class.

Answer (score 1):

BigInteger is easy to use and you don't risk precision problems with it. (In this particular instance I don't think there is a precision problem, because `Math.pow(2, 1001) % 100000` returns the correct last 5 digits, but for bigger numbers eventually you will lose information.) Here's how you can use BigInteger:

```
groovy:000> b = new BigInteger(2L)
===> 2
groovy:000> b = b.pow(1001)
===> 214301721437253464189685009812000362112280962341106721488750077674070210224
98722449863967576313917162551893458351062936503742905713846280871969155149397149
60786913554964846197084214921012474228375590836430609294996716388253479753511833
1087892154125829142392955373084335320859663305248773674411336138752
groovy:000> ((b + "").toList().collect {new Integer(it)}).inject(0) {sum, n -> sum + n}
===> 1319
```

Here's the same thing in Java:

```
public class Example
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int sum = 0;
    for (char ch : new java.math.BigInteger("2").pow(1001).toString().toCharArray()) {
      sum += Character.digit(ch, 10);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to the javadoc for NumberFormat: [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

just replace last line:

```
System.out.println(result);
```

with

```
System.out.printf("%d", result);
```